# GoogleChart JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, charts, google-visualization

Trying to create a google GANTT Chart using JSON Data via PHP and AJAX in a local host. I am getting the following error. I am unable to understand the error and how it's loaded.:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
    at gvjs_Tba (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:132)
    at new gvjs_R (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:131)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ganttchart.html:23)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:6)
gvjs_Tba @ jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:132
gvjs_R @ jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:131
(anonymous) @ ganttchart.html:23
c @ jquery.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4
k @ jquery.min.js:6
r @ jquery.min.js:6
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery.min.js:6
drawChart @ ganttchart.html:18
Promise.then (async)
google.G.K.U.hl @ loader.js:231
(anonymous) @ ganttchart.html:11
```

My HTML DOC where I do an AJAX reference to the PHP page. I changed the AJAX call from the previous version to include done

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "getGanttData.php", // make this url point to the data file
        dataType: "json"
      }).done(function (jsonData) {
        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var options = {
          //explorer: {axis: 'horizontal'}
          height: 275,
          gantt: {
            defaultStartDateMillis: new Date(2019, 1, 1)
          }
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="intro">
    <h1>Supervisor's Dashbaord</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP Script - This reads teh sample gantt details string and pulls the data: getGanttData.php

```
<?php 

$string = file_get_contents("sampleGanttData.json");
echo $string;

?>
```

My JSON Data: sampleGanttData.json

```
    {
  "cols": [{"id": "ID", "label": "Task ID", "type": "string"},
         {"id": "Name", "label": "Task Name", "type": "string"},
         {"id": "Resource", "label": "Resource", "type": "string"},
         {"id": "Start", "label": "Start Date", "type": "date"},
         {"id": "End", "label": "End Date", "type": "date"},
         {"id": "Duration", "label": "Duration", "type": "number"},
         {"id": "Percent", "label": "Percentage complete", "type": "number"},
         {"id": "Dependencies", "label": "Dependencies", "type": "string"}
  ],
  "rows": [
            {"c":[{"v": "T101"},
             {"v": "WO:1 - create Design"},
             {"v": "Engineer"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v": 2.0},
             {"v": 2.0},
             {"v":"null"}
        ]},

        [{"c":[{"v": "T102"},
             {"v": "WO:1 - Gain Design Approval"},
             {"v": "Engineer"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v": 3.0},
             {"v": 0.0},
             {"v":"T101"}
        ]}
        ]
  ]  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you will need to remove `async: false` to remove the deprecation warning

however, this will cause the rest of the chart code to run before the data has returned,
which will cause a different error

since the `success` function has also been deprecated,
move the rest of the code to the `done` promise to correct the issue,
as follows...

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function toMilliseconds(hour) {
  return hour * 60 * 1000 *60;
}

function drawChart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "getGanttData.php", // make this url point to the data file
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
      //explorer: {axis: 'horizontal'}
      height: 275,
      gantt: {
        defaultStartDateMillis: new Date(2019, 1, 1)
      }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

the json data is malformed. there is an extra opening and closing array brace in the second row, see comments.

```
{
  "cols": [{"id": "ID", "label": "Task ID", "type": "string"},
         {"id": "Name", "label": "Task Name", "type": "string"},
         {"id": "Resource", "label": "Resource", "type": "string"},
         {"id": "Start", "label": "Start Date", "type": "date"},
         {"id": "End", "label": "End Date", "type": "date"},
         {"id": "Duration", "label": "Duration", "type": "number"},
         {"id": "Percent", "label": "Percentage complete", "type": "number"},
         {"id": "Dependencies", "label": "Dependencies", "type": "string"}
  ],
  "rows": [
            {"c":[{"v": "T101"},
             {"v": "WO:1 - create Design"},
             {"v": "Engineer"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v": 2.0},
             {"v": 2.0},
             {"v":"null"}
        ]},

        // the following opening brace ([) should be removed
        [{"c":[{"v": "T102"},
             {"v": "WO:1 - Gain Design Approval"},
             {"v": "Engineer"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v":"null"},
             {"v": 3.0},
             {"v": 0.0},
             {"v":"T101"}
        ]}
        ]  // <-- one of these closing braces should be removed
  ]  // <-- one of these closing braces should be removed
}
```

also, if you're going to use a `null` value, it should not be in quotes.

```
{"v":"null"}  // <-- bad
{"v":null}    // <-- good
```

however, at least one row should have a start and end date,
in the data sample supplied, both rows have null for the dates.

cleaning up the json should allow the chart to draw,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['gantt']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"id": "ID", "label": "Task ID", "type": "string"},
      {"id": "Name", "label": "Task Name", "type": "string"},
      {"id": "Resource", "label": "Resource", "type": "string"},
      {"id": "Start", "label": "Start Date", "type": "date"},
      {"id": "End", "label": "End Date", "type": "date"},
      {"id": "Duration", "label": "Duration", "type": "number"},
      {"id": "Percent", "label": "Percentage complete", "type": "number"},
      {"id": "Dependencies", "label": "Dependencies", "type": "string"}
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[
        {"v": "T101"},
        {"v": "WO:1 - create Design"},
        {"v": "Engineer"},
        {"v": null},
        {"v": null},
        {"v": 2.0},
        {"v": 2.0},
        {"v": null}
      ]},
      {"c":[
        {"v": "T102"},
        {"v": "WO:1 - Gain Design Approval"},
        {"v": "Engineer"},
        {"v": "Date(2019, 1)"},
        {"v": "Date(2019, 2)"},
        {"v": 3.0},
        {"v": 0.0},
        {"v": "T101"}
      ]}
    ]
  });

  var options = {
    height: 275,
    gantt: {
      defaultStartDateMillis: new Date(2019, 1, 1)
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem. :(

Comment: will you please edit the question with the latest version of your code? do you receive any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: First, I really appreciate the help.

I get the error below: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
    at gvjs_Tba (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:132)
    at new gvjs_R (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:131)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ganttchart.html:23)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:6)